# How to get a list of supported gdal formats within python

Tags: python, raster, gdal

Is there a way to get a list of installed gdal formats on a system with python? On the command line this can be done easily with:

```
gdalinfo --formats
```

...but can it be done in python?

Comment: Perhaps something similar than in this tutorial about vector drivers http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/layers.html.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`gdal.GetDriverCount()` will provide the number of drivers that `gdal` has. Combined with a simple loop, it is possible to list all the drivers.

```
import gdal
driver_list = []
for i in range(gdal.GetDriverCount()):
    driver = gdal.GetDriver(i)
    driver_list.append(driver.GetDescription())

# list comprehension
driver_list = [gdal.GetDriver(i).GetDescription() for i in range(gdal.GetDriverCount())]

# to get name as string
gdal.GetDriver(i).ShortName
```